# Update returning * and select result as rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to run a few updates in a single query returning *, and select the output as rows. I currently have

```
with
  foo as (update table set .. where id = $1 retuning *),
  bar as (update table set .. where id = $2 retuning *)
select * from table where id = $1 or id = $2;
```

That does what I'm looking for but feels like it could be improved. I almost got it working like this

```
select * from foo, bar
```

but it displays as a single row not two separate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want `union all` (or perhaps `union1):

```
select foo.*
from foo
union all
select bar.*
from bar;
```